# Knowing the standard deviation of 2 normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian

I'm learning linear algebra for data science on some site. There is a quiz and the result I've answered that I linked to the image. I'm curious about why the standard deviation part is wrong? As I calculated, the SD of the purple distribution is 50 (190-140) and the yellow is 40 (200-160). Can anyone explain to my why?

[image: 2 normal Distribution intersecting]

Any helpful answer would be very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> As I calculated, the SD of the purple distribution is 50 (190-140) and the yellow is 40 (200-160). Can anyone explain to my why?

Your values are not correct: you're measuring the size of the interval [min,max], but you would need at least to take into account the frequency of the values in every bin in order to approximate the std. dev.

Additionally imho the test is unlikely to expect an answer as precise as the one you tried to obtain. It probably expects that you would visually compare the two curves, see that they are roughly the same size, and answer the second option (for instance you can see in the first question that when they want an answer "increase", they show a large difference to make it clear).